# Proving $\frac1{2^n}<\frac1n$ inductively

Tags: induction

I know this is probably a trivial proof but I'm struggling with it for some reason. The base case is trivial. I'm stuck at the inductive step where
$$\frac1{2^{n+1}}<\frac1{n+1}$$
I'm completely stumped and I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from
$$\frac1{2^n}<\frac1n$$
we divide both sides by 2:
$$\frac1{2^{n+1}}<\frac1{2n}$$
Since $2n>n+1$ if $n>1$:
$$\frac1{2n}<\frac1{n+1}$$
Hence
$$\frac1{2^{n+1}}<\frac1{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

You might aswell prove $2^n>n$, right?
The inductive step is

$2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n>2n\geq n+1$

Note that because $n\geq1$ then indeed $2n\geq n+1$.